# Ktor testApplication request cannot remove Accept Header

Tags: kotlin, testing, ktor

I'm trying to test ktor. And, then, compare the response and request that I've done with previous snapshot. It was working on the 1.6.x version. But, when I upgraded, I had to change the testing function to `testApplication`. Which makes available a `client`, so you can request.

```kotlin
fun `my test`() = testApplication {
        val response = client.request("/v1/mytest") {
            method = HttpMethod.Get
            addClientVersionHeaders()
            headers {
                remove(HttpHeaders.Accept)
            }
        }

        snapshotter.matchWithSnapshot(response)
    }
```

The problem is that the request does not allow me to remove the `"Accept"` header from the headers, it always use "*/*" as a default for `"Accept"` even though I have explicitly remove it from the headers list.

So, how to properly remove the header from request ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable default transformations to prevent adding the `Accept` header if one is missing in a request. Unfortunately, this also disables transformations of a body upon sending a request and receiving a response so, for example, `response.bodyAsText()` won't work anymore.

```
val client = createClient {
    useDefaultTransformers = false
}
```